# Python: reshape matrix to collection of lists

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I am stuck on a basic question. I want to enter a matrix:

```
                                    [1 2 3
                                     4 5 6
                                     10 9 1]
```

but I want it to be in the form:

```
                               [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[10,9,1]]
```

Do these representations have any specific names? What does that comma and double square brackets denote? I know this is a really silly question, but how do you convert it to the desired form?

Comment: In the first screenshot it is not clear : do you have a list that looks like [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,9,1] ? and you want to make it lokks like [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[10,9,1]] ? or do you have a matrix object ?

Comment: Yes, first I want to generate a vector of random numbers of length say 9, and then make it look like what i have shown.

Comment: I post an answer....let me know if it's work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

**1) Plain python**

**First step: Generate a list of 9 numbers**

```
import random

randomlist = []
for i in range(0, 9):
    n = random.randint(1, 30)  # change for the value you desire here... for the moment it will give you a random numbers btween 0 to 9
    randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist)
```

**Second step: make it to desired reshape (list of three lists) :**

```
desiredoutput = [randomlist[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(randomlist), 3)]
print(desiredoutput)
```

**2) Using numpy**

Reproduce the first step of solution 1 to get an array of random numbers. Then:

```
import numpy

sourcelist = numpy.asarray(randomlist)
desiredoutput = sourcelist.reshape(3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is python `numpy` library which allows you to reshape your arrays into a form you want, not python lists

```py
import numpy as np


a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 1])
print(a)
# [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  9 10  1]

b = a.reshape(3, 3)
print(b)
# [[ 1  2  3]
#  [ 4  5  6]
#  [ 9 10  1]]
```